# Angular handle circular class attribute refrences

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, I am struggling with setting up mock data. I have the following 2 classes:

```
export class Company {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public applications: Application[];

  constructor(id: number, name: string, applications: Application[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.applications = applications;
  }
}

export class Application {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public company: Company;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, company: Company) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.company = company;
  }
}
```

Now I also created these services:

```
export class CompanyService {

  companies = [
    new Company(
      1,
      'Company 1',
      []
    ),
    new Company(
      2,
      'Company 2',
      [],
    ),
  ]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Company[] {
    return this.companies;
  }

  findById(id: number): Company | undefined {
    return this.companies.find(company => company.id === id);
  }
}



export class ApplicationService {

  applications = [
    new Application(
      1,
      'Application 1',
      // COMPANY HERE SOMEHOW?
    ),
    new Application(
      2,
      'Application 2',
      // COMPANY HERE SOMEHOW?
    ),
  ]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Application[] {
    return this.applications;
  }

  findById(id: number): Application | undefined {
    return this.applications.find(application => application.id === id);
  }
}
```

Now somehow when I create this mockdata I need to add a company to the constructor of application, but when I add a company there, that object needs to contain the application in the constructor as well. This causes a chicken/egg problem and I am not sure how I should define this then.

I am new to Angular, so I don't know if there is a trick in the framework to use, or that I should use id's of the classes, but by using id's I still have the same problem. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps think of it like this. A company doesn’t need to have applications in order for it to exist, but an application likely does need a company in order to be created.

So create companies first, then create applications using an appropriate company, then add the applications to the company’s application list at the point of creating the applications.

Or ask, do you need companies to have applications listed like that? Perhaps you could just search all applications for those with the company you’re looking for rather than linking them to the company like that.

This is more about data modelling than Angular, and compounded by creating this in a mock way which is different to real world where the company would always exist before an application could be made.

Hope that helps.

How to “fix” it? Don’t create the data in the service? Create it separately, perhaps in a data service, and query it from the services you have there, which is more like how a real situation would be.